# Explaining parentNode

Tags: javascript

This isn't a help me solve something kind of question rather a explain what this does type question.

I understand what parentNode does but I can't wrap my head around the context of how it works with my code. The reason I was able to write the code was through a YouTube tutorial.

I was learning how to create a todo list app where you were able to add stuff and remove it. I made the remove button but the code I don't understand is how the remove function works in the code.

By my understanding, I'm thinking that it deletes the child which is the LI from the parent which is the UL?

If someone could explain the removeItem() function and what the code does I would very much appreciate it.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input'),
button = document.getElementById('add')

function removeItem() {
  
  var item = this.parentNode
  var parent = item.parentNode
  parent.removeChild(item)
  
  }

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var p = document.querySelector('p')
  if (input.value.trim() === '') {
    p.style.display = 'block'
    return false
  }
  
  p.style.display = ''
  
  var userInput = document.createTextNode(input.value)
  var li = document.createElement('li')
  var ul = document.getElementById('todo')
  
  var remove = document.createElement('button')
  remove.innerHTML = 'Remove'

  remove.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
  
  ul.insertBefore(li, ul.childNodes[0])
  li.appendChild(userInput)
  li.appendChild(remove)

})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"/>
  
<button id="add">Add</button>

<p>plz add</p>

<ul id="todo"></ul>
```

Comment: "*I'm thinking that it deletes the child which is the LI from the parent which is the UL?*" - Yes. Do you need any further explanation?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild

Comment: If you're curious, you should be adding console logs and breakpoints: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The best way to remove a node in Javascript is from its parent, using the removeChild() function.

You could use the remove() function like item.remove(), but this will not work with IE because in IE this function does another thing, it removes an option from a drop-down list (select).

So, to achieve cross-browser behavior, it is used the removeChild approach.